# CATS API - Can't access name

Tags: api, axios

I am trying to create a dropdown list of all the possible breeds of this API. When I try to dig deeper into the response console log gives back Undefined.

```
    axios.get('https://api.thecatapi.com/v1/breeds', options)
    .then((response) => {
      self.setState({ cats: response.data.breeds })
      console.log(response.data.name);
    }, (error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
```

Used code for console.log: `console.log(response.data.name);`

What should be used here to not get it back as undefined?

[image: axios-response-logger and console.log]

Comment: I think it is response.data[0].name

Comment: That gave me back something, thanks! Next question would be, how to loop it through all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To loop through all the data use this code.

```
axios.get('https://api.thecatapi.com/v1/breeds', options)
.then((response) => {
  response.data.forEach((singleCat) => {
    // Perform action with single cat here
   })
}, (error) => {
  console.log(error);
});
```

Another thing I noticed is you don't need to do self. inside es6 syntax